# How to find the correlation between columns starting with Open_ and Close_?

Tags: python, pandas, correlation

I'm trying to find the correlation between the open and close prices of 150 cryptocurrencies using pandas.

Each cryptocurrency data is stored in its own CSV file and looks something like this:

```
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|         Date        |       Open       |       Close      |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
| 2019-02-01 00:00:00 |    0.00001115    |    0.00001119    |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
| 2019-02-01 00:05:00 |    0.00001116    |    0.00001119    |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|         .           |        .         |         .        |
```

I would like to find the correlation between the `Close` and `Open` column of every cryptocurrency.

As of right now, my code looks like this:

```
temporary_dataframe = pandas.DataFrame()
for csv_path, coin in zip(all_csv_paths, coin_name):
    data_file = pandas.read_csv(csv_path)
    temporary_dataframe[f"Open_{coin}"] = data_file["Open"]
    temporary_dataframe[f"Close_{coin}"] = data_file["Close"]
# Create all_open based on temporary_dataframe data.


corr_file = all_open.corr() 
print(corr_file.unstack().sort_values().drop_duplicates())
```

Here is a part of the output *(the output has a shape of `(43661,)`)*:

```
Open_QKC_BTC     Close_QKC_BTC      0.996229
Open_TNT_BTC     Close_TNT_BTC      0.996312
Open_ETC_BTC     Close_ETC_BTC      0.996423
```

---

The problem is that I don't want to see the following correlations:

- between columns starting with `Close_` and `Close_`*(e.g. `Close_USD_BTC` and `Close_ETH_BTC`)*
- between columns starting with `Open_` and `Open_` *(e.g. `Open_USD_BTC` and `Open_ETH_BTC`)*
- between the same coin *(e.g. `Open_USD_BTC` and `Close_USD_BTC`)*.

In short, the perfect output would look like this:

```
Open_TNT_BTC     Close_QKC_BTC      0.996229
Open_ETH_BTC     Close_TNT_BTC      0.996312
Open_ADA_BTC     Close_ETC_BTC      0.996423
```

*(PS: I'm pretty sure this is not the most elegant to do what I'm doing. If anyone has any suggestions on how to make this script better I would be more than happy to hear them)*

Thank you very much in advance for your help!

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply, that's exactly what I want, I also don't want to have the coin compared between itself  (e.g. `Open_USD_BTC` and `Close_USD_BTC`)

Comment: Sorry I wrote my comment too fast, you have stated your problem very clearly. (I deleted my comment)

Comment: @VegardKT I've tried explaining in bullet points. I'll try editing it right now to make it a bit clearer

Comment: This is what i would do: Create a binary array for each of your problems, where you assign true / false if the current row matches your problem. Add these together then simply drop all rows where your final array is true

Comment: Have you tried to use [pandas profiling report](https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/JosPolfliet/pandas-profiling/blob/master/examples/meteorites.ipynb)? It may help you to quickly have a glance on your dataset correlations.

Comment: @pazitos10 Thank you very much for your advice. pandas profiling report looks really good but I doesn't really solve my issue

Answer (score 1):

This is quite messy but it at least shows you an option.

Her i am generating some random data and have made some suffixes (coin names) easier than in your case

```
import string
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


#Generate random data
prefix = ['Open_','Close_']
suffix = string.ascii_uppercase #All uppercase letter to simulate coin-names

var1 = [None] * 100
var2 = [None] * 100

for i in range(len(var1)) :
    var1[i] = prefix[np.random.randint(0,len(prefix))] + suffix[np.random.randint(0,len(suffix))]
    var2[i] = prefix[np.random.randint(0,len(prefix))] + suffix[np.random.randint(0,len(suffix))]

df = pd.DataFrame(data = {'var1': var1, 'var2':var2 })

df['DropScenario_1'] = False
df['DropScenario_2'] = False
df['DropScenario_3'] = False
df['DropScenario_Final'] = False

df['DropScenario_1'] = df.apply(lambda row: bool(prefix[0] in row.var1) and (prefix[0] in row.var2), axis=1) #Both are Open_
df['DropScenario_2'] = df.apply(lambda row: bool(prefix[1] in row.var1) and (prefix[1] in row.var2), axis=1) #Both are Close_
df['DropScenario_3'] = df.apply(lambda row: bool(row.var1[len(row.var1)-1] == row.var2[len(row.var2)-1]), axis=1) #Both suffixes are the same

#Combine all scenarios
df['DropScenario_Final'] = df['DropScenario_1'] | df['DropScenario_2'] | df['DropScenario_3']

#Keep only the part of the df that we want
df = df[df['DropScenario_Final'] == False]

#Drop our messy columns
df = df.drop(['DropScenario_1','DropScenario_2','DropScenario_3','DropScenario_Final'], axis = 1)
```

Hope this helps

P.S If you find the secret key to trading bitcoins without ending up on r/wallstreetbets, ill take 5% ;)

Comment: ahahah doing my best, hopefully, will get there one day. I don't quite understand where to put your code in reference to mine (before after). if you could incorporate my code or at least a few of my variables into the answer that would be great! thank you very much

Comment: This code will not work "in" your code. This is an example to show you how it can be solved. It will be hard for me to incorproate it because i do not exactly know how your variables work.